# what is the difference between walk path cycle circuit trial in a graph

Tags: graph-theory

In graph theory what is the difference between the above terms, different books gives different answers can anybody give me the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

**Walk**

A finite sequence of alternating vertices and edges...
A walk can be open: first and last vertex are not equal.
or closed...

**Trail**

Walk in which every edge us traversed only once.

**Path**

Trail with each vertrex visited only once (except perhaps the first and last)

**Cycle**

Closed walk with each vertex and edge visited only once

**Circuit**

According to wikipedia:

A circuit can be a closed walk allowing repetitions of vertices but not edges; however, it can also be a simple cycle, so explicit definition is recommended when it is used.

Good luck with the rest of the course...